# How to convert byte[] to String with no encoding, no loss of data

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array of bytes. The 8-bit value of each byte is what I want as the characters in my String. You can think of my 8-bit values as ASCII, ANSI, UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, daily temperature readings, distance in inches from a point on a line, or whatever you want. It's irrelevant.

When I'm done. the char at position N in my String should have the same value as the byte at position N. That is, the high-order 8 bits should be 0 and the low order 8 bits should be the same as the source byte.

What Encoding do I use that simply maps bytes to chars with no change?

Comment: Just curious what the need for this is. That string will not be very useful - it won't be usable for display or printing, and probably won't place nicely with any external systems. Why convert it from the bytes?

Comment: @JoeEnos why wouldn't the string be usable for display or printing?  Depending on the data in the byte array, it might very well be.

Comment: @JoeEnos, the purpose of phrasing the question as I did was to try to keep from getting a bunch of "why are you doing this?" and "the need to bypass encoding is a red flag indicating your solution is just wrong" answers. The question is the boiled-down form of my problem, or simply, how do I turn an array of bytes into a String without all the smart guys at Microsoft munging my data because they think they know better than I do what I'm trying to do. :-)

Comment: No prob - I absolutely understand not trusting Microsoft's implementation for some things (AJAX comes to mind). Just curiosity as to your requirement, since a string is generally only useful when it is regular text, and this won't be. Personally I'd trust a byte array or a base-64 encoded representation in my code before I trust a funky-looking string.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For this requirement, I would dispense with encodings, because I don't know the details of what they do, and just convert the bytes myself.

```
string Convert(byte[] data)
{
    char[] characters = data.Select(b => (char)b).ToArray();
    return new string(characters);
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what I was doing but was making an error somewhere else that masked my success. :-)

Comment: how about the other way around please? how to convert the string created by this method back to the byte array?

Comment: Many options.  The one with the least typing: `s.ToCharArray().Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();` -- where s is the string.  Note that this solution depends on the assumption, valid given the original question, that all characters are in the range 0 to 255.  In other contexts, you'll need to use a text encoding.

Answer (score 5):

The encoding you're asking about is called "[ISO/IEC 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)".

If you have .NET 5.0 or newer, the standard library provides that encoding in the [Encoding.Latin1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.latin1?view=net-7.0) property.

If you are using old runtime, call [GetEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoding?view=netframework-4.7.2) method, with code page argument `1252`

Comment: The object name is Latin1 in .NET string rcv = Encoding.Latin1.GetString(lclBuffer), documentation mouse over will confirm this is ISO-8859-1

Answer (score -2):

What about using [*extended* ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)?

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(437).GetString(bytes);
```